# React: cant get data via API

Tags: reactjs, ajax, react-native, api

I am new here and  with React. I tried to get data via APı but I could not get any. Also, I did not get any error message as well. This is my code. I tried to add if statement to check whether data is fetched or not. When I check console I got the error message. Where did I wrong? Thanks for your time.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

  class PokemonList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: result.items
        });
      },
      // Note: it's important to handle errors here
    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
    // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
      }
    )
}
render() {
  const { error,isLoaded, items } = this.state;
  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
   } else if (!isLoaded) {
   return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
      
    return (
        
        <ul>
        {items ? items.map(item => (
          <li>
             <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>;
          </li>
        )) :
        console.log('no data')}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

}
export default PokemonList;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pokémon items you're trying to get have a `results` key, not `items`. So replace `result.items` with `result.results` and see what happens.

Comment: You can always have a look at json data in your browser just to get a quick view of its structure. And there are browser extensions you can install to make it readable like this one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en

Comment: How should I know that?   is it written anywhere_ I am jut asking for  next projects.

Comment: now I got this error: : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Did you get your data to load by making the change I suggested?

Comment: How can I know that it is result key or result item.  Is there a place they are defined like so?

Comment: Then take my suggestion, install a json formatter for your browser and have a look at the data yourself. Your app is loading the data, but you're not properly mapping over it. Examining the structure of the json should give you a clue as to what is wrong.